# Add Cut file/folder option to right click or Context menu

Tags: macos, shortcut-menu

I use Lion on my Macbook pro 13". I would like to add a context menu item called "Move" or "Cut" (just like Copy) and when I go to the desired location and hit "Paste", it should Move the file/folder I selected and paste it there. Is this possible in Lion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, install TotalFinder.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you add some details to this? What is TotalFinder, where can we get it, and how will it help in this situation? Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: That's great! Thank you. It is available as a free 14 day trial here
http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/

The paid version is $18, but the author can give you free license if you meet his criteria mentioned here.

http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/free-licenses

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no.

Assuming you may be an ex-Windows user, you cannot perform a "Cut" and "Paste" with files or folders in Mac OS X Lion, or previous versions for that matter like you can in Windows.

Your only option is to drag and drop to move, or "Copy" and "Paste" then delete the original afterwards.

Comment: Actually, in Lion, you can move items (sort of). Copy an item, then hold down the option key while pasting. The file will be copied to the new location and the original will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, it is much faster than copying and deleting.

Answer (score 2):

As commented above, both <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>
Or <kbd>option ⌥</kbd> + secondary click + paste work on Mountain Lion